# install visual studio professional on a mac, only community will install for me

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to install Visual Studio Professional for mac from here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/

No matter which version I down load, Community, Professional or Enterprise it is always Community that get's installed.

Anyone else having this issue and know a work around?

Comment: I have got the same problem.  The Account menu item is not available and I get MonoDevelop on the start page instead of this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/signing-in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. But was able to solve it with the following steps:

1. Go to VisualStudio -> Account
2. Log in with an Account which has the vs Professional/Enterprise license
3. Restart Visual Studio

After these Actions the window title states "Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 for Mac"

Comment: My unit test projects won't load, I am guessing this is why - di you have this issue?

Comment: @Slee, did you find out the problem with yours unit test projects? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Slee I have the same problem with unit-test project. it was not able to load. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that Visual Studio will not let you log in because it thinks you are not online.  If you are on Wi-Fi try connecting with a wired connection.